# zend framework create empty display group and then add element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Is possible to create an empty display group and then add the elements?

I tried:

```
addDisplayGroup(null, 'exampleGroup')
```

But you have to pass at least an element...

I need to create just an empty display group.

I need to do that because after create the display group, I will add the elements one by one in a foreach....

Thanks again...

Comment: just put the elements in an array during your foreach and then pass it to ->addDisplayGroup

Comment: Hi Max, Yes at the end I did it like this...   I tought about it...   I just want it in the other way because the code looks more easy to understand...   Anyway is ok...   Thanks again....

Answer (score 2):

You could try with

```
$form->addDisplayGroup(array(), 'exampleGroup');
```

and then get the display group like that:

```
$displayGroup = $form->getDisplayGroup('exampleGroup');
```

and add the elements one by one later with `$displayGroup->addElement()` or `$displayGroup->createElement()`.

You can see more details in the [Display Groups documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.displaygroups).

**EDIT**:

ZF doesn't allow to add a display group with no elements. The simplest solution could be to create the elements first, put them into an array, and then pass that array to `addDisplayGroup`.

It's also possible to instantiate a new `Zend_Form_DisplayGroup` object and then add it to the form using `$form->addDisplayGroups(array($group))`, but I doubt if it's more convenient than calling `addDisplayGroup()` with the elements already created.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer dinopmi...   I tried before your way but it doeasn't work...  It return an exception: No valid elements specified for display group.

Comment: In that case, as @max4ever notes in his comment, it would be easier just to create the elements first and call addDisplayGroup after they are ready...

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding the form's `addDisplayGroup($elements, $name)` method, adding a dummy element if necessary:

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{

    protected $dummyName = '_myDummy';

    public function addDisplayGroup(array $elements, $name)
    {
        if (count($elements) == 0){
            $elt = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden($this->dummyName);
            $elt->setIgnore(true);
            $elements[] = $this->dummyName;
        }
        return parent::addDisplayGroup($elements, $name);
    }

    public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null)
    {
        $this->removeElement($this->dummyName);
        return parent::render($view);
    }
}
```

Then in your form you can now invoke as:

```
$displayGroup = $this->addDisplayGroup(array(), 'myDisplayGroup');

$elt1 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('myElement1');
$displayGroup->addElement($elt1);

$elt2 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('myElement2');
$displayGroup->addElement($elt2);

// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$zgody = $db->fetchAll($db->select()->from('rodo_regulki')->where( 'id_inwest =?', $inwest ));

$getFirstElement = $zgody[0]->id;
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('zgoda_'.$getFirstElement),'zgody', array('legend' => 'Zgody'));

foreach($zgody as $zgoda) {
    $element = 'zgoda_'.$zgoda->id;
    $addElement = $this->getElement($element);
    $displayGroup = $this->getDisplayGroup('zgody');
    $displayGroup->addElement($addElement);
}
```